# I would like to filter out the {closed} and {on hold} questions from my results

Tags: support

How do I filter the questions/answers shown on the home page and in search results?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to exist already. Try adding `closed:0` to your search.

Lots more details [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/searching).